# Having trouble making account

Tags: discussion, tagging

I asked a question on here recently and started the process of creating an account, but when I clicked the "set your password" link in the confirmation email it just made me a new account. What's going on, and how do I get into my old account?

Comment: Perhaps related: [Author unregistered](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/5667/5764) You need to contact Stack Exchange and ask them to merge accounts if that's the case.

Comment: That seems to be the issue. I have done as you suggested, and just need to wait for them to get back to me.

Comment: This solution worked and the issue is now resolved.